# How to send a welcome message to a specific channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

When a user enters my server, I plan to send a welcome message on a specific channel.
However, this code does not work.
(+I don't even get an error)

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.guild.get_channel(channel ID).send(member.mention + "text")
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

First I dont believe you need to return anything although I might be wrong.
However try this,

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    
    channel = client.get_channel(int(channel_id))
    print(channel)
    await channel.send('whatever you need to send')
```

and just in case remember that channel ID is an int